# Python: Recursion depth exceeded error

Tags: python

I reworked the program to get large prime numbers. Now it works fine, except I get a large number of red phrases at the end, after all the output is printed. Could someone please tell me why?

The end is of the output is:

```
(100000939.0, 'is prime')
(100000963.0, 'is prime')
(100000969.0, 'is prime')
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marcela/Documents/Prime numbers to 100", line 48, in <module>
    loopfunction()
  File "C:/Users/Marcela/Documents/Prime numbers to 100", line 35, in loopfunction
    loopfunction()
  File "C:/Users/Marcela/Documents/Prime numbers to 100", line 35, in loopfunction
    loopfunction()
  File "C:/Users/Marcela/Documents/Prime numbers to 100", line 35, in loopfunction
    loopfunction()
...(many lines of it, the int ends with:) 
File "C:/Users/Marcela/Documents/Prime numbers to 100", line 13, in loopfunction
    while index <= 200000000.0:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

Here is the script:

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
index=100000000.0
checker=2.0



def loopfunction():
    global index
    global checker
    checker=2

    while index <= 200000000.0:

        if index>=200000001:
            sys.exit(1)
        while checker<=14473.0:

            div = index/checker
            roundiv=round(index/checker, 0)
            if index == 1:
                print (index, "is prime")
                checker=2
                index=index+1
                loopfunction()   
            if checker == index:
                print (index, "is prime")
                checker=2
                index=index+1
                loopfunction()
            if roundiv==div:

                checker=2
                index=index+1
                loopfunction()    

            if checker==14473.0:

                print (index, "is prime")
                checker=2
                index=index+1
                loopfunction()

            checker = checker +1



loopfunction()
```

Comment: What is a "red phrase"?  Please show us your output.

Comment: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object, that's your error really, the other lines are due to that

Comment: Thanks -- is there is way to avoid exceeding the maximum recursion depth?  To me it seems like the script is logical.

Comment: The "red stuff" is: (100000937.0, 'is prime')
(100000939.0, 'is prime')
(100000963.0, 'is prime')
(100000969.0, 'is prime')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marcela/Documents/Prime numbers to 100", line 48, in <module>
    loopfunction()
  File "C:/Users/Marcela/Documents/Prime numbers to 100", line 35, in loopfunction
    loopfunction()
  ......(lots more the same!)... File "C:/Users/Marcela/Documents/Prime numbers to 100", line 13, in loopfunction
    while index <= 200000000.0:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

Comment: Why are you relying on globals instead of passing arguments to recursive calls?

Comment: It's possible to define recursive depth, sys.setrecursionlimit(), but I think this is unwise really

Comment: A better suggestion would be to convert recursion to iteration.

Comment: I can reset recursion limit (to 5000) and it goes farther, but only to a point. I have tried iteration, using "for" but still got the red phrases.

Comment: @user1460981: Setting the recursion limit wont help because it would fail when you give it larger numbers. Please convert your logic to iteration.

Comment: Thanks Thrustmaster, you mean using a "for" statement, right?

Comment: @Robert -- that's a good question, but I still thought that globals could do this without exceeding the recursion depth. It's not because the numbers are big -- it does it with small numbers, starting from 1 up with smaller parameters, with the recursion level exceeded at 97.

Comment: @user1460981 it can probably work with globals, yes, but it's generally easier to follow when globals aren't used.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your recursion limit issue by simply not recursing. Your code already has the loops you need.

Just change the calls to `loopfunction()` in the various if statements to `break`.

While that is all that is needed to make the code function, I've noticed though that some of number of your if statements are unnecessary (either redundant with the loop conditions, or simply impossible to ever hit). You're also using `while` loops where `for _ in range()` loops would make more sense. Here's a greatly simplified version of your code, with some things renamed to clarify their purposes:

```
from math import sqrt

def primeFinder(start, end):
    prime = True

    for index in range(start, end):
        for checker in range(2, int(sqrt(index))+1):
            if index % checker == 0:
                prime = False
                break

        if prime:
            print("%d is prime" % index)

        prime = True

primetest(100000000, 200000001)
```

This version will still take a very long time (probably hours). If you really want to test a hundred million values for primeness, you should probably investigate a better algorithm, such as the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: EXCELLENT!! I changed those three instances to "break" and it works like a charm, with numbers of ANY size. No more red phrases. You are a lifesaver, and great kudos to you my friend! Your own ode is more streamlined and better, but to get a grip on this I still wanted to know why my own wasn't working -- just change the function calls to break and presto.